# Convert list comprehension to traditional approach

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I am trying to get myself familiar with list comprehension as much as possible. I have the following pythonic loop:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
for result in p.imap_unordered(process_next, [(x1, models, y1) for _ in range(iterations)]):
    # some stuff
```

I am not sure if it is equivalent to:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) 
for result in p:
    p.imap_unordered(process_next, [(x1, models, y1)])
    M = []
    for _ in range(iterations):
        M.append(_)
```

Kindly, can someone verify my understanding? Thank you

Comment: No, it isn't equivalent. You should probably start with examples that don't involve multiprocessing as an irrelevant distraction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list comprehension is one argument to a call to `p.imap_unordered()`; you'd need to extract it first:

```
_arg2 = [(x1, models, y1) for _ in range(iterations)]
for result in p.imap_unordered(process_next, _arg2):
    # ...
```

Now you can expand that into a traditional `for` loop:

```
_arg2 = []
for _ in range(iterations):
    _arg2.append((x1, models, y1))
for result in p.imap_unordered(process_next, _arg2):
    # ...
```

The `for result in p.imap_unordered()` loop and call are otherwise independent from the list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you for your reply